# how to add json file to android project

Tags: java, android, json

I am simply trying to add a .json file into my android studio project. Most of what I have run into has you create a folder and add it there but I want to simply move it over under app. [Here Is my project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKVyh.png)

[How to add JSON files to my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928877/how-to-add-json-files-to-my-project)

[Add JSON file to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730470/add-json-file-to-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891943/adding-static-json-to-an-android-studio-project

Comment: May I know the exact reason you want it under the app and not in a folder?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> I want to simply move it over under app

If you literally mean that you want to have `app/something.json`, you are welcome to put the file there, but it will not be packaged with your app, and it will not be available to you at runtime.

If you want to ship the JSON with your app, you have four major options:

- Put it in `assets/` and read it in using `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream`
- Put it in `res/raw/` and read it in using `Resources` and its `openRawResource()` method
- Hardcode it as a string in Java code
- Write yourself a code generator that converts JSON into a Java class that you would access like you do the code-generated `R` and `BuildConfig` classes

It is possible that such a code generator already exists. I have [a rudimentary Gradle plugin](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/Staticizer) that does this, as an example that I'll be including in the next update of [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android).

Comment: Wait, out of assets folder, I can run it with no errors. Are you sure that we have to put only and only on assets file? I have some concerns because I could run it without doing it like that you mentioned.

Comment: @Bay: "I can run it with no errors" -- sorry, but I do not know what "it" is. "Are you sure that we have to put only and only on assets file?" -- I listed four options in my answer, not just one.

Answer (score 21):

Please follow the steps below and json file in our project.

step 1 : Change Android to Project

Step 2 : create assets Folder and put json file like login.json

[image]

I hope it will help you...!

Answer (score 0):

Put it androidTest/assets/
Just create `file`, like a `SomeFile.json`